# How can I show in printhelp that an option can be solicited many times?

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I am using commons-cli library to manage options passed to my command. 
Am building a helpformatter to detail the usage for users.

## What am obtaing as output is that :

> usage: java mudebs.broker.BrokerMain
>
> startbroker --uri <-this broker URI-> [--neigh <-a remote broker URIs->]
>          [--log <-logger.level->] [--perfconfigfile <-arg->]

but since --neigh  and -- log can be sollicited multiple times for the same command

## I want to have such an output:

> usage: java mudebs.broker.BrokerMain
>
> startbroker --uri <-this broker URI-> [--neigh <-a remote broker URIs->...]
>          [--log <-logger.level->...] [--perfconfigfile <-arg->]

Is that possible ?

Comment: Why don't you simply change the description ? It's more explicit than `...`

Comment: yeah, that's possible but am just wondering if there is an explicit method for it . Am looking as well for showing that two options alternate. like [--content <content> | --file <filepath>] , just to  show that the use of both is not possible . I think commons-cli library lacks expressiveness.

Comment: I personally would keep things simple, look at the example in the javadoc of [Help Formatter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/HelpFormatter.html) You could add in the detailed description that filepath cannot be used with content and vice versa

Comment: yes, you are right. Thank you for  help .